# MySQL server doesnt creates a stored procedure via phpmyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-error-1064

```
delimiter //
create procedure rankPagesLive()
BEGIN 
    SET @r=0;
    UPDATE pageslive SET Rank= @r:= (@r+1) ORDER BY fan_count DESC;
END //
delimeter ;
```

---

> Error'#1064 - You have an error in
>   your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'delimiter // create procedure
>   rankPagesLive() BEGIN
>       SET @r=0' at line 1

---

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with phpmyAdmin and not with SQL code, `delimiter` identifier isn't allowed via SQL query (probably on my server only),

After I logged in to MySQL server by SSH - it works just fine.

Thank you for contribution.

Answer (score 2):

Last line should be:

```
delimiter ;
```

Comment: @rkcell: `delimiter`, not `delimeter`. Note the `i` instead of `e`.

Comment: oh... you're right... but the mentioned problem begin at line 1 - phpMyAdmin wasnt allowed to use `delimiter` )))

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single query in a way like this

```
update pageslive as p
inner join (
 select @r:=@r+1 as rn,id
    from pageslive,(select @r:=0) as r order by fan_count desc
     ) as t
 on p.id = t.id
 set rank = rn
```

but IMHO I would avoid to store a calculated field within the table. You can always get this value with a simple select.